# The product rule of f differentiable a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable a.e, does the product rule still hold? For the special case when $g=1/f$, does the rule hold?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The product rule holds in any point where both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. Does the set of points where neither $f$ nor $g$ is differentiable have measure zero?

Answer (score 1):

The rule still holds, yes, since at worst the rule would fail on the union of the two sets where f and g fail to be differentiable.

As the union of two null sets, this set would also be null, so in its complement (i.e. almost everywhere) the product rule will still hold.